# How to return a string?

Tags: java, string

```
import java.util.*;
public class HangManP5 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
int attempts = 10;
int wordLength;
boolean solved;
Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Hey, what's your name?");
String name = k.nextLine();
System.out.println(name+ ", hey! This is a hangman game!\n");
RandomWord(word);
int len = word.length();
char[] temp = new char[len];
for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
{
    temp[i] = '*';
}
System.out.print("\n");
System.out.print("Word to date: ");
while (attempts <= 10 && attempts > 0)
{
    System.out.println("\nAttempts left: " + attempts);
    System.out.print("Enter letter: ");
    String test = k.next();
    if(test.length() != 1) 
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter 1 character");
        continue;
    }
    char testChar = test.charAt(0);
    int foundPos = -2;
    int foundCount = 0;
    while((foundPos = word.indexOf(testChar, foundPos + 1)) != -1)
    {
        temp[foundPos] = testChar;
        foundCount++;
        len--;
    }
    if(foundCount == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Sorry, didn't find any matches for " + test);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Found " + foundCount + " matches for " + test);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(temp[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();

    if(len == 0)
    {
        break; //Solved!
    }
    attempts--;
 }

if(len == 0)
{
    System.out.println("\n---------------------------");
    System.out.println("Solved!");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("\n---------------------------");
    System.out.println("Sorry you didn't find the mystery word!");
    System.out.println("It was \"" + word + "\"");
}
}
public static String RandomWord(String word)
{
//List of words
Random r = new Random();
int a = 1 + r.nextInt(5);
if(a == 1)
{
    word=("Peace");
}
if(a == 2)
{
    word=("Nuts");
}
if(a == 3)
{
    word=("Cool");
}
if(a == 4)
{
    word=("Fizz");
}
if(a == 5)
{
    word=("Awesome");
}
 return (word);
 }
 }
```

Ok, so this is my code for a hangman game, the only thing I have left to do is to get my program to randomize one of the words, which it should do in the method successfully. But the only problem I'm having is getting the String variable *"word"* to go back to the main class (there are errors underlining all the *"word"* variables in the main class).

If I could get help with either this or another way to produce a random word from a list, that would be amazing.

Comment: There is no reason that `RandomWord` should take the parameter `String word`.  You do not make any use of that parameter.  Your syntax errors could be related to that.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand how to declare a variable in Java: `<type> <name> = <object>`. So, `RandomWord(word)` is not the correct way to initialize a `String word` with the random word. Instead, you should use `String word = RandomWord()` (assuming you remove the String parameter, as Eric mentions.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't declaring the variable, I was calling the method. @Vulcan

Comment: @BuySomeChips I can see that. If you want to do anything with the output of the method, you'll need to declare a variable and assign it the method's output.

Comment: Thanks guys, I got it down now. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Feel free to post your working code over at [codereview.se] - many people have learned many things from the Java community over there ;)

Comment: Eyy! @retailcoder Thanks for the recommendation, will do!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In java, parameters are passed by value and not by reference. Therefore, you cannot change the reference of a parameter.

In your case, you need to do:

```
public static String getRandomWord() {
    switch(new Random().nextInt(5)) {
        case 0:
            return "Peace";
        case 1:
            return "Nuts";
        // ...
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("Something went wrong!");
    }
}
```

And in `main`:

```
// ...
String word = getRandomWord();
int len = word.length(); 
// ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't modify the caller's reference.

```
RandomWord(word);
```

needs to be something like

```
word = RandomWord(word);
```

Also, by convention, Java methods start with a lower case letter. And, you could return the `word` without passing one in as an argument and I suggest you save your `Random` reference and use an array like

```
private static Random rand = new Random();
public static String randomWord() {
    String[] words = { "Peace", "Nuts", "Cool", "Fizz", "Awesome" };
    return words[rand.nextInt(words.length)];
}
```

And then call it like

```
word = randomWord();
```